# android: how to display the URL of a media file stocked on a media server with cling upnp stack

Tags: android, url, upnp

I'm using Cling upnp stack java, and I detect all upnp devices with my android control point, then i browse a media server and i list the media files ( video, audio ..) .
this code display the name of file that i clicked on it like ( videoname.mp4 ), i want to display all the URL, like ( 192.168.1.2:9000/video/videoname.mp4)

how can i do this ?

```
public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        upnpService = (AndroidUpnpService) service;
        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                        long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    ServerContent item = listAdapter.getItem(position);
                    Log.e("onitemclick","listadapter");
                    item.select();
                    Log.d(item.toString(),"test 1");
                    Log.e(item.getClass().getSimpleName(),"test 2");
                }
            });
            browseServer("0");

        }
```

Comment: What **Cling** class is your `ServerContent` deriving from?

Comment: I get the url from the item given by the servercontent thx pavel for your help.